# Normalize data in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization

I have an SQL query `A` (see below for more details) that returns a table as following:

```
cluster  brand  amount
0         bos     600
0         phi     300
0         har     100
1         pro    2500
1         wal    1500
1         ash    1000
2         dil    4200
2         sor     500
2         van     300
...
```

However, I want to show not the amount, but the fraction of that amount compared to the total amount in that cluster, like in the following table:

```
cluster  brand  amount
0         bos    0.60
0         phi    0.30
0         har    0.10
1         pro    0.50
1         wal    0.30
1         ash    0.20
2         dil    0.84
2         sor    0.10
2         van    0.06
...
```

How should I change my SQL such that I can get access to the sum over all amounts in one cluster, and still have multiple rows with the same cluster?

**** Details ****

SQL server: MySQL, interfaced through the python-MySQL connector.

Current SQL query to generate the first table:

```
SELECT c.cluster, brand, COUNT(o.id) AS brand_amount
FROM nyon_all.clustering AS c 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.persons AS p ON c.pid = p.id 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.orders AS o ON p.id = o.pid 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.articles AS a ON o.aid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.brands AS ab ON a.brand_id = ab.id 
WHERE c.cluster_round = 'Org_2014-08-27_10:45:35'
GROUP BY cluster, brand 
HAVING brand_amount > 100
ORDER BY c.cluster ASC, brand_amount DESC;
```

Table `orders` (primary key `id`) links `persons` (foreign key `pid`) with `articles` (foreign key `aid`). `Articles` have a certain brand (foreign key `brand_id`), which are related to a name in the Table `brands`.

The total amount of articles per cluster can be retrieved with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT c.cluster, COUNT(o.pid) AS amount
FROM nyon_all.clustering AS c 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.persons AS p ON c.pid = p.id 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.orders AS o ON p.id = o.pid 
WHERE c.cluster_round = 'Org_2014-08-27_10:45:35'
GROUP BY cluster
ORDER BY c.cluster ASC, amount DESC;
```

Result:

```
cluster amount
0        1000
1        5000
2        5000
```

However, I can't seem to combine the two SQL queries.

Comment: data is Normalized in TABLES not in SQL query! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a join on a subquery summing the amount by cluster

```
select t1.cluster, amount / sumAmount 
from Table1 t1
join (select cluster, sum(amount) as sumAmount
      from Table1
      group by cluster)s
on t1.cluster = s.cluster
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29b1e/4)

EDIT

```
SELECT 
    c.cluster, 
    brand, 
    COUNT(o.id) / coalesce(s.sumBrandAmount, 0) AS brand_amount -- of course it would be nice to check for dividing by 0
FROM nyon_all.clustering AS c 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.persons AS p ON c.pid = p.id 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.orders AS o ON p.id = o.pid 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.articles AS a ON o.aid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN nyon_all.brands AS ab ON a.brand_id = ab.id 
LEFT JOIN (select c1.id, count(o1.id) as sumBrandAmount
           from nyon_all.clustering c1
           left join nyon_all.persons p1 on p1.id = c1.pid
           left join nony_all.orders as o1 on o1.id = p1.id
           --maybe some where clause as in your main query
           group by c1.id) s
                               ON s.id = c.id
WHERE c.cluster_round = 'Org_2014-08-27_10:45:35'
GROUP BY cluster, brand 
HAVING brand_amount > 100
ORDER BY c.cluster ASC, brand_amount DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand it. Should I substitute Table1 with my big query? If I try to do so, I receive an Error Code 1054: Unkwown column 'amount' in 'field list'.

I am unfamiliar of SqlFiddle. The link shows me two empty squares. What should I do with it?

Comment: @physicalattraction seems there's some problem with SqlFiddle (doesn't always work)... I'll try to edit my answer with your query.

Comment: @physicalattraction see edited answer. Of course, to make things easier to read, you could create a view based on your question's query, and use it rather then rewriting all...